# How to avoid / repair permission problems between Mojave and Catalina

Tags: macos, mojave, catalina, permission, dual-boot

I installed Catalina (clean install) to a new volume in the same APFS Container like Mojave. Then I  created a volume "Shared Data" that contains all personal data that I moved from "/Mojave/users/... to the new volume "Shared Data", incl. cloud data like Google Drive, Dropbox and OneDrive.

First it seemed to work, but then I remarked permission problems when switching between the two OS Catalina and Mojave.

1) How should the permissions look like on that "Shared Datas" volume ?

2) How can i repair / set this permissions for the already moved data ?

3) How do I avoid different permissions while working ?

[image: diskutil list]

User 502 is Mojave (4E7ABC2B-2DA4-...)

[image: Mojave user]

User 501 is Catalina (B9723800-87FD-...)

[image: Catalina user]

Comment: Please add the output of `diskutil ap list` and the UIDs of the main user of each system install (Catalina & Mojave) who share the data (e.g. `id -u $USER`) to your question **as formatted text**.

Comment: The permission problems arise from the different user ids (502 (Mojave) vs. 501 (Catalina)). You probably have a second user with the id 501 in Mojave. Traditional Unix permissions are set/evaluated by user id/group ids! The main user of each system volume should have an identical uid/gid to avoid permission problems on shared data volumes like yours. Your real problem is (or might be) different though: you have "unified" (=Mojave & Catalina) preboot **and** recovery volumes. The "shared" vm volume is harmless probably.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "unified". I used some German guides for this installation https://www.sir-apfelot.de/macos-catalina-ohne-partition-parallel-zu-mojave-installieren-26981/ and https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT208891. Can I change the uid/gid in Catalina ?

Comment: Usually preboot and recovery are os specific. Example: recovery (Mojave) contains a base system with some slimmed 10.14 system and recovery (Catalina) a base system with some slimmed 10.15 system. Considering the size of your recovery volume (1 GB) it contains both (the normal size is ~500+ MB).

Comment: Personally, I would have created a second **container** and installed Catalina there. I have never tested your setup scheme.